# Scheduled task on Azure that runs a webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, azure, scheduled-tasks

I have a data-driven view on an Azure site that renders a lot of JavaScript/ CSS / XML and HTML from a third party plugin and generates a PDF which is emailed to a user.

I need to call this page on a weekly schedule for each user - and with Azure Jobs it's really straightforward to set this up. But obviously there will be no JavaScript engine to render the code that generates the PDF, so what are my options?

Would I have to go down the route of installing NodeJS on my Azure instance? If so what are the steps and other modules required.

The site is running MVC C# and has a SQL back end.

Cheers for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If code you need to run can be factored / extracted as a Node.js app, you can run it as a scheduled **Azure WebJob**. You can find details on how to do that [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/). You don't need to install Node.js - it's already installed on all the Azure App Service workers.

One thing to note is that WebJobs run an **execution sandbox** (details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/)) and there are some restrictions on what is allowed to run in the sandbox. So you'd have to experiment to see if your PDF library runs successfully there.

For example, one of the popular libraries for PDF generation **wkhtmtopdf** will not work on Azure App Service. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642451/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net-on-azure) discusses this in more detail. One user has successfully hosted wkhtmtopdf on an Azure VM and offers it as a **service that you can call**.

Comment: Hey mathewc .. I've gone the Node route but having some issues - as you can see in this new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056467/azure-and-node-js-and-jsdom-scheduled-task-opening-a-webpage-with-scripts